# difference between ldmia.w sp, {r1, r2} and ldmia.w sp!, {r1, r2}?

Tags: assembly, arm, stack-memory, addressing-mode

I am working in a binary analysis project and I came across two different variants of ldmia arm assembly instruction.

ldmia.w  sp, {r1, r2}

ldmia.w  sp!, {r1, r2}

I know ldmia.w  sp!, {r1, r2} is a synonym to pop {r1,r2}.
but what about ldmia.w  sp, {r1, r2}? . Am I using the value stored in sp as a memory address to load from into r1 and r2 which doesn't make much sense to me or am I poping from the stack without updating the value of the sp which also doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the ARM Architecture Reference Manual for the meaning of the various parts of the ARM assembly language.  The `!` sign denotes that the new address is written back to the register.  I.e. `ldmia.w sp!, {r1, r2}` adds 8 to `sp` but `ldmia.w sp, {r1, r2}` leaves `sp` unchanged.

Comment: yes that i know... but what is the usage of each instruction?..is ldmia.w sp, {r1,r2} used to implement a stack pop without updating sp or is it a memory load taking sp as the base register??

Comment: the reason why usage is important to me because I am translating each instruction to an LLIR  and  I have constructed my own memory and stack models..so I need to capture the effect of each instruction on my models.

Comment: @hanyerfan Each of these instructions can be used for a variety of purposes.  You will not be able to uniquely assign a usage to each instruction.

Comment: @fuz *adds 4* - two 32-bit registers are read by ldmia.w sp!, {r1, r2}, so it adds 8, doesn't it?

Comment: @tum_ Yes, indeed.

Comment: @fuz ..ill try to  narrow down my question more... can the sp register be used in instructions other than those poping and pushing onto the stack?

Comment: @hanyerfan Yes of course.  Why should it not?

Comment: yes i just realised i should have my stack model as part of my memory model.....one last question.. what happens to the memory space of a register being popped off the stack?

Comment: @hanyerfan Popping a register off the stack is a load operation.  It does not modify memory.  However, the memory location of the register is now below the stack pointer and thus can be overwritten by an interrupt handler or similar at any time.

Comment: ```ldmia.w sp, {r1, r2}```would just load the top item of the stack into both ```r1``` and ```r2```, and the stack pointer would remain pointing to the same value.

Comment: @hanyerfan The values popped off the stack are still there (for now), until some other function overwrites them when it pushes more values. Nearly all programs treat that memory as "gone" after you've popped it off the stack, and don't try to access it directly.